# How to select only cells with values on different sheets, without switching over to that sheet?

Tags: vba

I currently have a macro that copies and paste data from one sheet to another sheet, based on a certain criteria. I have over 15 sheets that it does this.

Now what I want to do is select all the data in the new sheets, and turn it into a table.

I know I can use ActiveSheet, but I would need to do that for every single sheet. Is there a way I can select only the data in other sheets, without that being my active sheet?

I am able to select all my data in an active sheet with this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B1:M1", ActiveSheet.Range("B1:M1").End(xlDown)).Select
```

I tried doing something like below, but just selects the last cell with data in it. If I remove the .End(xlDown), then it will select B1:M1.

```
  Application.Goto Sheets("SheetName").Range("B1:M1").End(xlDown)
```

Any idea if there is a way to copy my data in those ranges without switching tabs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid Select/Selection/Active/ActiveXXX, like follows:

```
With Sheets("SheetName")
    .Range("B1:M1", .Range("B1:M1").End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:= someotherrange
End With
```

Where someotherrange is a valid range reference where to paste copied data into